# Update mysql query if user closed his Broswer

Tags: php

If user logged in then it's show status is "ON" because of i run the query to show that the user is now ONLINE:

**Online:**

```
$sqlonline = mysql_query("INSERT INTO useronline VALUES('$_SESSION[id]', '$uname', '$ip', 
'$time', '', 'ON')");
```

And If user is logged out then I update the query to show that the user is OFFLINE

**Offline**

```
$q=mysql_query("UPDATE useronline SET status = 'OFF',  time_out  = '$time' WHERE 
session_id ='$_SESSION[id]'");
```

Well, My question.. Is there any way to update the query to status = **'OFF'** if user closed his/her browser? Now it's show User is Now **ONLINE** if user closed the browser. I want if user closed the browser then it's show user is now **"OFFLINE"**

Can anyone give me a idea!
Sorry my bad english:(

Comment: And again another duplicate. And if you search the site and wonder that there is no actual and easy solution for that, read the more lengthier answers.

Comment: Second hakre. There is no reliable way to do something on browser close. You could do this if the user actually went to a "logout" link, else you need to just refer to a timestamp of their last action.

Comment: what happened hakre? this is my own questions

Comment: @Shibbir: We all own all questions on this site, it's like a wiki. So you don't own a question or an answer, it's all shared. It's not accepted to duplicate questions needlessly as well in this community, this is not how this site works. Please read the FAQ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reliable way to send something to the server in the moment user're trying to close the browser tab. You need to write to database time of the last request came from user. When this time goes far enough in the past, it means the user is gone.

Comment: Not impossible, but not reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and do this with Javascript and check for a window close event, but it's up to the browser on whether that is supported.

What you could do instead is create a table to log when people visit your site, and then run a cron job to check how long it has been since they changed pages. If it's been longer than X minutes set that user's status to offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update to db when the user has closed the window.

You can update by checking at regular intervals to db.

You can have a field in db named last_updated_time. If the user logins, update current time in this column every few(3 or 5) seconds from the user's page using setInterval() or setTimeOut() method.

If the user had closed the window, last_updated_time won't updated.

In the page where you want to show online/offline status, check the time difference between the current time and the last_updated_time of the user. If the time difference is long, update the user status to OFF and show offline status.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by using jquery above 3

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function(){
   // and use browser online function navigator.onLine;
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22054238)